# How is domain_taxonomy_access module configured?

Tags: 7, domain-access

I am trying to use the domain_taxonomy_access module, but I do not know how it is configured.

How I do so that the user of a certain domain can manage their newsletters?

I am trying to implement the solution shown here: https://www.drupal.org/project/domain/issues/558692

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution by myself.

I use domain access with simplenews, i need the [Domain Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/rolfmeijer/2050999) to,

What you have to do, is go to:

```
structure / taxonomy / [yourtaxonomynewsletter]
```

Then `edit some term` of the taxonomy and at the end of the configuration called `Term source domain` there is an option to set the domain to the taxonomy.